# Can't get Facebook Deferred Deep Link in my app with Facebook App Ads Helper

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, deep-linking, facebook-unity-sdk

I check pending deferred deeplinks on different devices and android versions
and some devices cant get deferred deeplink.

But when I reset Advertising ID in device settings, device starts get deferred deeplink

```
void Start()
{ 
 if (FB.IsInitialized)
        {
            FB.ActivateApp();
        }
        else
        {
            FB.Init(() => {
                FB.ActivateApp();
                FB.Mobile.FetchDeferredAppLinkData(DeferredAppLinkData);
            });
        }
}

void DeferredAppLinkData(IAppLinkResult result)
    {
        string targetUrl = string.Empty;
        completeLink.text = result.ToString();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.TargetUrl))
        {
            targetUrl = result.TargetUrl;
            deepText.text = targetUrl;
        }

        deepText.text += "'n  = " + targetUrl;

    }
```